# Boundedness of binomial coefficient multi-index [hold-on]

Tags: analysis, combinations

Let be $\alpha,\beta\in \Bbb{N}^n$ multi-index, such that $|\alpha|=m+1$ e $\beta <\alpha$, with $m\in\Bbb{N}$ fixed.

Is it possible to bound $\large\large{\alpha \choose \beta}$ by something that depends on $m$?

I.e, is there a function $f$ depending on $m$, such that

$${\alpha \choose \beta}\le f(m)?$$

Some hint to explicit the function $f$?

> **Def:** $${\alpha \choose \beta}:={\alpha_1 \choose \beta_1}\cdots{\alpha_n \choose \beta_n}=\frac{\alpha !}{(\alpha - \beta)! \beta !}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first suppose $n=1$, if $\alpha=m+1$ then ${\alpha \choose \beta}\leq {m+1 \choose \lfloor (m+1/2)\rfloor}$. Moreover, if $j\leq l$ so ${j \choose \lfloor j/2 \rfloor}\leq {l \choose \lfloor l/2 \rfloor}$. In general, $|\alpha|=m+1$ then $\alpha_i\leq m+1, \ \forall i\leq n$. Then ${\alpha \choose \beta}\leq {m+1 \choose \lfloor (m+1)/2 \rfloor}^n$.

Comment: Perfect Davi! Very good!